# VBA Storing Output Results in Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

```
Sub myArrayRange()

Dim iAmount() As Variant
Dim iNum1 As Double

'For Input of S.No
iAmount = Range("A1:A1000").Value2

'Main Code
For iNum1 = 1 To UBound(iAmount, 1)

    Worksheets("Cashflows").Range("C3") = iNum1
    Model_cv = Worksheets("Cashflows").Range("C20")


iAmount = UBound(Model_cv, 1)

        
Next iNum1
End Sub
```

In the above code what I am trying to do is Update the worksheet `Range("C3") = iNum1` (which loops through 1 to 1000).
In the Second step worksheet Range("C20") is updated from which I want to pick the value from the range and store it in VBA Array once the loop is finished then paste the values to the Excel worksheet.

Comment: Are you looking for `iAmount(iNum1, 1) = Model_cv`?

Comment: Model_cv is my output which i want to store as an array. And then loop for next iNum1

Comment: If you read from a single cell though (`.Range("C20")`, you don't have an array.

Comment: I am so confused what exactly you're trying to do. You say you're looping through the 1000 rows and want to store values to an array to write it back to the sheet in one go but you do exactly the opposite. You access C3 every iteration by placing the iteration in it (each time). Then you access C20 each iteration and place them in the same (non defined) variable which all of a sudden is supposed to be an array? The whole point of using arrays is to use the sheet as less as possible.

Comment: Maybe it will be easier to understand if you give us some example data. (before and after)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are attempting to loop through the values from 1 to 1000 using the variable iNum1. Within each iteration of the loop, you update cell C3 in the "Cashflows" worksheet with the current value of iNum1. Then, you assign the value of cell C20 to the variable Model_cv.

However, there are a few issues with your code. First, you are overwriting the `iAmount` array with the result of `UBound(Model_cv, 1)`, which doesn't seem to be the intended behavior. Instead, you should declare a separate array to store the values from cell C20.

Here's an updated version of your code that stores the values from cell C20 in an array and then pastes the array values to an Excel worksheet after the loop:

```
Sub myArrayRange()
    Dim iAmount() As Variant
    Dim iNum1 As Long
    Dim Model_cv As Variant
    Dim resultArray() As Variant
    Dim pasteRange As Range
    
    'For Input of S.No
    iAmount = Range("A1:A1000").Value2
    
    ' Resize the result array based on the size of iAmount
    ReDim resultArray(1 To UBound(iAmount, 1))
    
    'Main Code
    For iNum1 = 1 To UBound(iAmount, 1)
        Worksheets("Cashflows").Range("C3") = iNum1
        Model_cv = Worksheets("Cashflows").Range("C20").Value
        
        ' Store the value in the result array
        resultArray(iNum1) = Model_cv
    Next iNum1
    
    ' Set the paste range for the result array
    Set pasteRange = Worksheets("Result").Range("A1").Resize(UBound(resultArray))
    
    ' Paste the values from the result array to the worksheet
    pasteRange.Value = Application.Transpose(resultArray)
    
End Sub
```

In this updated code, the result array `resultArray` is declared and resized based on the size of `iAmount`. Within the loop, the value from cell C20 is assigned to Model_cv and then stored in the corresponding index of `resultArray`.

After the loop, the paste range pasteRange is set to the destination worksheet (in this case, "Result") and resized based on the size of resultArray. Finally, the values from `resultArray` are transposed and pasted to the worksheet using the `pasteRange.Value = Application.Transpose(resultArray)` statement.

Comment: You can Redim your resultArray to `Redim resultArray(1 To UBound(iAmount,1),1 To 1)` so you don't need to transpose later, just fyi. Also, why not store the value in the array immediately instead of using the intermediary `Model_cv` ?

Comment: @Notus_Panda Because in his post he use a `Model_cv`. So I kept it but you are right we can simply do : 
`resultArray(iNum1) = Worksheets("Cashflows").Range("C20").Value`